# Polly create HttpClient (IHttpClientBuilder.AddPolicyHandler) without ServiceCollection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, .net-7.0, polly

I am trying to use `IHttpClientBuilder.AddPolicyHandler` method of `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly` to create an instance of HttpClient with Polly policies built-in. However, I am not using an IoC and ServiceCollection. How to create `IHttpClientBuilder` without ServiceCollection and IoC so I can use the extension method `AddPolicyHandler`. Even If I have an instance of `IHttpClientBuilder`, how to create a HttpClient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to have DI to decorate an `HttpClient` with a policy. You can do that via the `PolicyHttpMessageHandler`. The trick here is to set the `InnerHandler` to `HttpClientHandler`.

```cs
var policy = ...;
var policyHandler = new PolicyHttpMessageHandler(policy);
policyHandler.InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();   
var httpClient = new HttpClient(policyHandler);
//the usage of the httpClient
```

Comment: Thank you! - Took so long to find this :)